# Dataframe : replace value and values around based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, replace

I would like to create a filter to replace values in a dataframe column based on a condition and also the values around it.

For exemple I would like to filter values and replace then with NaN if they are superior to 45 but also the value before and after it even if they are not meeting the condition:

```
df[i] = 10, 12, 25, 60, 32, 26, 23
```

In this exemple the filter should replace 60 by NaN and also the value before (25) and the value after (32).The result of the filter would be :

```
df[i] = 10, 12, NaN, NaN, NaN, 26, 23
```

So far I am using this line but it only replace value that meet the condition and not also values around:

```
df[i].where(df[i] <= 45, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare original with shifted values of mask chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m = df['i'].gt(45)

mask = m.shift(fill_value=False) | m.shift(-1, fill_value=False) | m

#alternative solution +1, -1 value by parameter limit
#mask = df['i'].where(m).ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1).notna()

df.loc[mask, 'i'] = np.nan
```

Another idea for general mask (but slowier like solution above):

```
mask = (df['i'].rolling(3, min_periods=1, center=True)
               .apply(lambda x: (x>45).any()).astype(bool))

df.loc[mask, 'i'] = np.nan
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for having a mask on a lower and upper condition ?

Comment: @Ketchup - Do you think up e.g. 3 values and down e.g. `1` value? Then use `mask = df['i'].where(m).ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=3).notna()`

Comment: Meaning if a value is not between [lower, upper] replace it and its neighboors by NaN

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean mask to filter the dataframe column  and replace the value with Nan.

```
mask = (df["col"] > 45)
df.loc[mask, "col"] = np.nan
```

After this you can use the mask to replace the values immediately before and after each value that met the  condition with NaN as well.

```
df.loc[(mask.shift(1) | mask) | (mask.shift(-1)), "col"] = np.nan
```

Comment: Do you have a solution for having a mask on a lower and upper condition ?